# Prevent new ta.crossover or ta.crossunder signal (plotshape) in a range of X bars after the last ta.crossover or ta.crossunder

Tags: pine-script

I am trying to prevent the generation of new crossover or crossunder within a range of X bars after the last crossover or crossunder was triggered : meaning when a crossover or crossunder is triggered no new crossover (if a crossover as been triggered before) or crossunder (if a crossunder as been triggered before) can be triggered with the range of X bars.

I have tried to code it, but basically what my code do is shifting the signal ahead of X bars and marking bar where no crossover or crossunder is actually happening.

```
//@version=5
indicator("[TEST] Test 3", overlay=true)

// --- Moving Average Basis Line Crossing
maOne = ta.ema(high,21)
plot(maOne, title='EMA', color=color.new(#43f09f, 0), linewidth=1, style=plot.style_line)
// --- end
// --- Moving Average Basis Line Crossing
maTwo = ta.ema(close,50)
plot(maTwo, title='EMA', color=color.new(#f34369, 0), linewidth=1, style=plot.style_line)

condLongMA  = ta.crossover(maOne,maTwo)
condShortMA = ta.crossunder(maOne,maTwo)

var bool cond = na
if condLongMA
    cond := true
if ta.crossunder(maOne, maTwo)
    cond := false

sinceLastLongCrossover = ta.barssince(condLongMA)
barsCond = nz(sinceLastLongCrossover) == 75

// condLongMA
// (cond and barsCond)
plotshape(condLongMA, style=shape.triangleup, location=location.bottom, color=color.green, size=size.auto, title='Buy', display = display.all)
// plotshape(condShortMA, style=shape.triangledown, location=location.bottom, color=color.red, size=size.auto, title='Sell', display = display.all)
```

Would appreciate some help, since I am stuck since a few days now.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can record the Last time you draw a triangle for your crossunder.crossover and then each time anew croosunder/crossover appears, compare the bar_index to the bar_index of the last crossover/crossunder.

Here is a working example :

```
//@version=5
indicator("[TEST] Test 3", overlay=true)

// --- Moving Average Basis Line Crossing
maOne = ta.ema(high,21)
plot(maOne, title='EMA', color=color.new(#43f09f, 0), linewidth=1, style=plot.style_line)
// --- end
// --- Moving Average Basis Line Crossing
maTwo = ta.ema(close,50)
plot(maTwo, title='EMA', color=color.new(#f34369, 0), linewidth=1, style=plot.style_line)

condLongMA  = ta.crossover(maOne,maTwo)
condShortMA = ta.crossunder(maOne,maTwo)

var BarIndexLastCrossOver = bar_index // Initialisation
GoLong = false
if condLongMA and (BarIndexLastCrossOver + 75 < bar_index)
    GoLong := true
    BarIndexLastCrossOver := bar_index

var BarIndexLastCrossUnder = bar_index // Initialisation
GoShort = false
if condShortMA and (BarIndexLastCrossUnder + 75 < bar_index)
    GoShort := true
    BarIndexLastCrossUnder := bar_index
// condLongMA
// (cond and barsCond)
plotshape(GoLong, style=shape.triangleup, location=location.bottom, color=color.green, size=size.large, title='Buy', display = display.all)
plotshape(GoShort, style=shape.triangledown, location=location.bottom, color=color.red, size=size.large, title='Sell', display = display.all)
```

Before :
[image]
After :
[image]

Comment: Works perfectly as expected! Appreciated!